# How to query ruby on rails chain relationships has_many than has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In rails, I have 3 models
`Category, SubCategory` and `Product`.

A `Category` **has_many** `Subcategory`
and A `Subcatetgory` **has_many** `Products`.

That's say there is a `movie Category` and a `TV Category`.
And the movie has `Subcategories` like *Scary/Drama/Comedy*...

How do I query top sell movies? 
I tried `@category.products` and it won't work .

It is ok for me to query `@category.subcategories` and `@subcategory.products` ?
Is there anyway to chain them up? So that I can find top sell products of movie category.

Comment: I want you to first go through rails documentation..http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to set your classes up so that you can call `@category.products`. You have to define a `has_many through` relationship on the Category class:

```
class Category
  has_many :products, through: :sub_categories
end
```

Now if you have `@category` and ask for `@category.products`, **ActiveRecord** will make two requests of the database. The first will look like this:

```
SELECT "sub_categories"."id" FROM "sub_categories" WHERE "sub_categories"."category_id" = $1  [["category_id", 1]]
```

This returns a list of `sub_category` ids that **ActiveRecord** will pass to the next query. Assuming the `sub_category` ids returned from the first query were 2, 4, and 5, then you would get this:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."sub_category_id" IN (2, 4, 5)
```

This all happens behind the scenes, and you'll get back a nice `Product::ActiveRecord Relation` that you can use as you normally would.

Comment: Nice and thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

In your category model, add the following,

`has_many :products, through: sub_categories`

Then you will be able to query directly.

Hope that helps.